# MySQL table inside another?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Sorry for my bad English in advance.

So I'm just starting to learn MySQL.

I'm trying to create a simple app, in which i must be able to create a "category of questions" (adding categories names), then in each category i must add a list of "questions", i made a simple html back office that contain an `<input>` (text field), a `<form>` (action="process.php") & a button of course.

Same code to add questions.

Here is the process.php code

```
<?php

include("includes/connect.php");
$cat_name=$_POST["cat_name"];

$reqAdministrateurs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (cat_name) VALUES ('$cat_name')");

header("location:categories.html");
?>
```

Everything works fine, I'm able to add categories name inside the MySQL table (that i called "categories"), now I'm little lost (well, a lot actually) how to create this list of question? I mean how can i add a question inside a specified "category"? Ah btw i made a drop-down-menu for the categories (but i don't know how to import categories list on it from the database), then once the category is selected, i must be able to add a question in it.

I hope i made myself clear & thanks

Comment: So table questions, which refers to category_id (or, name, but it's not considered good practice). One column - the category - second the question. This way when you have for category `X` 3 rows with questions, once you `SELECT questions WHERE category = 'X'`, you will recieve this 3 rows

Comment: phpMyAdmin **is not a database engine**

Comment: So my concept itself is wrong, it's not a table inside another but two tables linked together (right?), i'll try it & let you know thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

you need to maintain two tables for the same.

Table1 : **categories**

there should be a autoincrement primary key along with the category name.

**column names**

```
id (auto increment integer value)
name (varchar 200)
```

Table1 : **questions**

there should be a autoincrement primary key along with the question column.
and we have to maintain a category id as foriegn key in this table

**column names**

```
id (auto increment integer value)
question (may be text or varchar)
category_id (from table1 categories)
```

now you can insert the category name as you are doing currently with little change of your code for prevent sql injections

**Note :**  `mysql_*` is deprecate you must use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

```
<?php

include("includes/connect.php");
$cat_name=$_POST["cat_name"];

$cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string($cat_name); // prevent sql injections

$reqAdministrateurs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (cat_name) VALUES ('$cat_name')");

header("location:categories.html");
?>
```

now make a form which takes the input of your category id and quetion and submit it in table2 : question

i think now to onwards you do it yourself because of you are learner. and have to do more and more by yourself. if any problem or query regarding this i will definitly help you.